# Replace css when element is visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a right arrow that when clicked shows the hidden left arrow. There is text centered between the two arrows so the margin changes on the centered text when both arrows are visible so I removed the css styling on #completeList and am trying to add the css with JQuery. Here is the code that I am trying:

```
$('#completeList').css('margin-left', '44%');
if ($('#leftArrow').is(':visible')) {
$('#completeList').css('margin-left', '32%');
}
```

The shortened html is:

```
<p><img id="leftArrow"><span id="completeList"><img style="float: right" id="rightArrow"></p>
```

The problem I am having is the 44% margin-left is not changing to the 32% margin-left when $('#leftArrow') is visible.

Is the jQuery i used a viable solution or should I be looking for another way?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I'm pretty sure they're asking how to change the margin from `44%` to `32%`, when the `#leftArrow` is `:visible`

Comment: What do you want, huh..?

Comment: @ether but that doesn't provide any feedback on what's wrong or any other hint of a problem....and neither does the question

Comment: @charlietfl As I typed a response, I caught a spelling error in his code, so I think he just has something misspelled.

Comment: That was a typo to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try positioning the arrows absolutely. This removes the arrows from the context of the surrounding elements and allows them to be positioned relative to the parent `<p>` without affecting the adjacent text.

```
p {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px; /* Leave enough space for an arrow on each side*/
}
#leftArrow,
#rightArrow {
    position: absolute; /* position the arrows absolutely */
}
#leftArrow {
    left: 0;
}
#rightArrow { 
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't spell `#completeList` the same in both your statements.

```
$('#completeList').css('margin-left', '44%');
if ($('#leftArrow').is(':visible')) {
$('#completList').css('margin-left', '32%');
}
```

Try this:

```
$('#completeList').css('margin-left', '32%');
```

Comment: That was a typo to the post. Thanks for pointing it out though